# Implementing the Knights Tour with C#

Tags: c#, knights-tour

I'm trying to implement the Knights Tour problem in C#.

I refer to the C++ code in this link:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-1-the-knights-tour-problem/

I've been scratching my head for hours now, trying to figure out why my c# code (which almost identical to the C++ code) doesn't produce the same result. I think I'm actually stuck in an infinite loop for some reason.

Here is the C# code:

```
public static int[,] exampleMat = new int[,]
        { 
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
            { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 }
        };

        public static int[,] directions = new int[,] { { 2, 1 }, 
                                                       { 1, 2 }, 
                                                       { -1, 2 }, 
                                                       { -2, 1 }, 
                                                       { -2, -1 },
                                                       { -1, -2 }, 
                                                       { 1, -2 }, 
                                                       { 2, -1 } };

        public static void KnightsTourExec(int[,] mat)
        {
            exampleMat[0, 0] = 0;

            FindRoute(0, 0, 1, mat);
        }

        private static bool FindRoute(int currentX,int currentY, int times, int[,] mat)
        {
            if (times == 64)
                return true;

            for (int i = 0; i < directions.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                int moveToX = currentX + directions[i, 0];
                int moveToY = currentY + directions[i, 1];
                bool isInMat = moveToX >= 0 && moveToX < mat.GetLength(0) && moveToY >= 0 && moveToY < mat.GetLength(1);                

                if(!isInMat || mat[moveToX, moveToY] != -1)
                    continue;

                mat[moveToX,moveToY] = times;
                if (FindRoute(moveToX, moveToY, times + 1, mat))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    mat[moveToX, moveToY] = -1;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
```

Execution in Main method:

```
KnightsTour.KnightsTourExec(KnightsTour.exampleMat);
```

Comment: It works for me. I have just checked your code and it produces the same result. The only inaccuracy in your code is `exampleMat[0, 0] = 0;`, which should be `mat[0, 0] = 0;`, so that it can work with any external mat array.

Comment: are you sure ? It's runs continuously at my end

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that was the thing !!!!!!!!!!!!! damn... thanks man :)